# BCP format file editing for Bulk Import into SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I'm attempting to import a large amount of data contained in a CSV file into a SQL database. The CSV is 4g in size.  The CSV has 329 columns and 300,000+ rows of data. So far I've successfully created the database and table that will hold the data once imported.  The data contains string (VARCHAR(x), numeric (INT), and dates (DATE).

The data contained within the CSV file is separated by a deliminator "," but all of the data fields are encased in double quotes, with some fields not containing data values.  Below is a mock example of the data.

"123244234","09/12/2012","First Name","Last Name","Address 1","","","555-555-5555","","CountryCode"

In research I've determined the easiest way to import the data will be to use BCP to create a format file and then uses that with BULK INSERT.  The only probably is in formatting the format file to remove the double quotes.  When attempting to import without a format file it fails on row one because the first column first row is numeric and has "" around it.

I've reviewed the following link that talks about removing the double quotes "http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;132463" with the use of a dummy entry to remove the quotes.  In this case that is a lot of manual editing.  Does anyone know of a better way to edit the format file??  Here is a sample of the format file:

```
10.0
329
1       SQLCHAR             0       12      ","     1     NPI                            ""
2       SQLCHAR             0       12      ","     2     Entity Type Code               ""
3       SQLCHAR             0       12      ","     3     Replacement NPI                ""
4       SQLCHAR             0       9       ","     4     Employer Identification Number (EIN)                    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR             0       70      ","     5     Provider Organization Name (Legal Business Name)           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR             0       35      ","     6     Provider Last Name (Legal Name)                           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7       SQLCHAR             0       20      ","     7     Provider First Name                         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
8       SQLCHAR             0       20      ","     8     Provider Middle Name                         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
9       SQLCHAR             0       5       ","     9     Provider Name Prefix Text               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
10      SQLCHAR             0       5       ","     10    Provider Name Suffix Text
```

Comment: You could use a temporary table for the BULK INSERT, with all columns varchar(max), transform any columns that need converting to remove quotes, etc, then transfer the lot to the real table - `SELECT INTO FinalTable FROM TempTable` - bit of a chore for 329 columns :)

Comment: I'm gonna take a stab at this, but I have another question on using convert to remove quotes.  would it be better to use REPLACE? Ex: REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )   Can this be done as follows REPLACE (varchar, '""','')

Comment: Ok. I've started to attempt to BULK import into a temp table.. it appeared to be running fine for 12 minutes and then the following.  Msg 7119, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Attempting to grow LOB beyond maximum allowed size of 2147483647 bytes.  Any thoughts??  I'm on Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2796.0 (X64)  I saw a something on FILESTREAM?? thoughts

Comment: From a quick search, that suggests one Large OBject (field or row) is too large - is it treating rows correctly? Did any rows come in OK? Seems mad if there's a size limit to an import!

Comment: No rows came in at all.. failed completely..  Found this article at MSDN, so gonna read over and see what I can figure out..  still open to thoughts suggestions.. (i'm not a dba and pretty novice at this stuff)  link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188267

Comment: I've never used Format Files, but is there a way the quotes could be removed with that approach, making the temp table redundant? Anyway, if you can find a text editor that can open the 4GB file without blowing its brains out (try Notepad++) it's worth cutting out just the first few lines to give you a much smaller dataset to work with :) Good Luck, please let us know how you get on.

Comment: Ultraedit will open it and I've found out a bit more about the file.  I had only scrolled so far down because of slowness but looks like 1,000,000 + rows, so cutting out a few and testing is needed. I'm on my phone but I'll post in the command I ran last night with BCP later that also failed with an EOL error..  This will get figured out :)

Comment: Try using SSIS instead.  That sounds like a fairly standard CSV file with double-quote qualifiers around each field.  You can choose format mapping, destination fields, etc.  BCP is easy and fast, but I think you found the 'not so easy' part of the command-line tool ;)  SSIS bulk inserts are also quite fast, as long as the indexes in the destination table are off or disabled and the clustered PK is the only index that grows (and it grows in order of course).

Comment: i most often use a parser before importing.. i.e. a small script which goes trough the source file row by row and converts it to "normal" or "bcp-friendly" csv. use a language like python or perl for that script, they have a lot of convenient functions. the performance hit of copying 4GB of data is low compared to how much it simplifies the process.